# How to query the amount of orders that contain more than 1 unique product

Tags: sql, ssms, aggregate-functions, distinct

I have a sales table that contains columns such as id, order_number, product_number, other columns

| id | order_no | product_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 300 | 10 |
| 2 | 300 | 10 |
| 3 | 300 | 11 |
| 4 | 301 | 12 |
| 5 | 301 | 13 |
| 6 | 302 | 10 |
| 7 | 303 | 11 |
| 8 | 304 | 10 |
| 9 | 304 | 10 |
| 10 | 305 | 13 |
| 11 | 305 | 15 |
| 12 | 305 | 17 |

How do I write a query that returns all orders that contain more than 1 distinct product_number?  The result would be order_nos 300, 301 and 305

To take this a step further, imagine a product table that looks like so

| product_number | category |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 |
| 11 | 2 |
| 12 | 4 |
| 13 | 3 |
| 14 | 5 |
| 15 | 3 |
| 16 | 6 |
| 17 | 3 |

I want to find all orders that have more than 1 distinct product category, in this case I want to find just orders 300 and 301 as 305's orders are all from category 3.
Final step, how do I count these orders rather than just list them and compare this number to all orders? I want to be able see that there are 2 orders with 2 distinct categories and 5 orders in total.

Thanks in advance!

I have tried using a simple select query, joining the tables on product number and using HAVING count(distinct product_number) > 1, but if I change this to < 2 I get no results and if I remove this my results are the same, so clearly something has gone wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Final step, how do I count these orders rather than just list them and compare this number to all orders? I want to be able see that there are 2 orders with 2 distinct categories and 5 orders in total.

You can use two levels of aggregation:

```sql
select count(*) cnt_total_orders,
    sum(case when cnt_product_numbers > 1 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_multi_product_orders
from (
    select count(distinct product_number) cnt_product_numbers
    from mytable
    group by order_no
) t
```

This produces a resultset made of one row and two columns, with the first column showing the total count of orders and the second column counting only orders that have more than 1 distinct product.

On the other hand, if you want a resultset that shows how many orders have a given number of distinct products, we can slightly change the outer query:

```sql
select cnt_product_numbers, count(*) cnt_orders
from (
    select count(distinct product_number) cnt_product_numbers
    from mytable
    group by order_no
) t
group by cnt_product_numbers
```

Comment: Thank you, this has solved my answer.  I am a new account so can't mark your answer up or give it a tick.  But here is my tick in comment form
✔